# Spring-boot redirect:/ to http instead of https

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, weblogic

When redirecting to a relative path in spring-boot controller like below code. It is always redirecting to http url when the application is deployed in https environment. So I am getting mixed origin content blocked error in browser.

```
return "redirect:/redirectUrl";
```

The application is deployed in weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

First, open the application.properties file and add `server.http.port` property to define a port for HTTP, and `server.port` property for HTTPS.

**Note**: `server.http.port` is a property you define and not available in SpringBoot.

In application.properties file:

```
    # (User-defined Property)
    # Port for HTTP and read by Spring Boot via @Value("${server.http.port:80}")
    server.http.port=8080
    
    # Port for HTTPS and read by Spring Boot via @Value("${server.port:443}")
    server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: password
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: springboot
    key-password: password
  port: 8443
```

- `server.port`: the port on which the server is listening. We have used 8443 rather than the default 8080 port.
- `server.ssl.key-store`: the path to the key store that contains the SSL certificate. In our example, we want Spring Boot to look for it in the classpath.
- `server.ssl.key-store`-password: the password used to access the key store.
- `server.ssl.key-store-type`: the type of the key store (JKS or PKCS12).
- `server.ssl.key-alias`: the alias that identifies the key in the key store.
- `server.ssl.key-password`: the password used to access the key in the key store.

Next, create a `HttpHttpsConfig` class and configure Spring Boot to use both HTTP and HTTPS protocols at the same time.

```
@Configuration
public class HttpHttpsConfig {

    // (User-defined Property)
    @Value("${server.http.port:80}")
    private int httpPort;

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setPort(this.httpPort);

        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
        return tomcat;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you you can consider the references for different strategies and implementation.

[reference-1](https://o7planning.org/11867/configure-spring-boot-to-redirect-http-to-https)

[reference-2](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your WEB-INF/web.xml file...

```
<web-app>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>SecureResources</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

That should cause any http requests to be redirected to https.